# How do I write a SQL statement to count the number of back and forth messages between any pair of users?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am interested in having an output that gives me the number of back and forth messages between any given pair. I have seen some examples where the user ids were numeric and something like min max was used to create unique ids for each pair, but that won’t work in my case since my user ids are string.
The second thing is, I only want to count the back and forth messages between any pair. Meaning if one person sent 3 messages and only got one response, num_msgs_back_forth=1.

Here is a hypothetical view of my source table:

```
     msg_timestamp         | sender_id | receiver_id 
2022-03-04 21:29:58 UTC    | a_12b3    | a_34c6
2022-03-04 21:30:50 UTC    | a_12b3    | a_34c6
2022-03-04 21:30:57 UTC    | a_12b3    | a_34c6
2022-03-04 21:35:09 UTC    | a_34c6    | a_12b3
2022-03-04 21:40:10 UTC    | a_34c6    | a_77h3
2022-03-04 21:41:15 UTC    | a_77h3    | a_34c6
2022-03-04 21:43:20 UTC    | a_34c6    | a_77h3
2022-03-04 21:44:35 UTC    | a_77h3    | a_34c6
2022-03-04 21:50:18 UTC    | a_12b3    | a_77h3
2022-03-04 21:54:28 UTC    | a_12b3    | a_77h3
```

This is the output that I am hoping to get:

```
pair_id | pair_user_id1 | pair_user_id 2 | num_msgs_back_forth
     1  |   a_12b3      |   a_34c6       |      1
     2  |   a_34c6      |   a_77h3       |      2
     3  |   a_12b3      |   a_77h3       |      0
```

This is the logic that I am thinking after creating a unique pair id.

–check receiver of the previous msg
lag(receiver_id) over (partition by pair_id order by msg_timestamp) as previous_receiver

–remove follow up msg
Where previous_reciever is null or receiver<> previous_receiver

–checking how many back and forth this pair has exchanged
dense_rank()over(partition by pair_id order by msg_timestamp)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: mySql or BigQuery?

Comment: BigQuery. Thank you. I have updated the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
select row_number() over() pair_id , 
  pair_user_id1, pair_user_id2, 
  least(sum(path.x), sum(path.y)) num_msgs_back_forth
from (
  select *,
    least(sender_id, receiver_id) pair_user_id1, 
    greatest(sender_id, receiver_id) pair_user_id2,
    if(least(sender_id, receiver_id) = sender_id,  struct(1 as x, 0 as y), struct(0 as x,1 as y)) path
  from your_table
)
group by pair_user_id1, pair_user_id2
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: added a question above